# Перевод средств на WMR кошелек кликом на ссылке

Tags: webmoney

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос: существует ли какой либо "плагин" для перевода средств со своего кошелька на кошелек пользователя, допустим у пользователя в анкете указан его WMR, мы кликаем по этому кошельку и у нас открывается окно перевода средств со своего кошелька на данный?

я не нашел ничего дельного по запросу API WM - там нужно долго разбираться, неужели не существует что-то подобное "вставил код в определенном месте и пользуешься"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webmoney Merchant

Comment: Там только надо будет еще в своей панели управления поколдовать - добавить адрес страницы, + надо иметь какой-то аттестат и подтвержденные данные.

Comment: Нужно иметь аттестат продавца...
Остальное все просто, там простые редиректы идут на ссылки Мерчанта и обратно...

Answer (score 0):

в этом случае надо пользоваться АПИ ВМ, почитать можешь у них на сайте